# Convert ArrayList<Long> to ArrayList<String> with for loop

Tags: java, arraylist

Why do I get a NullPointerException when I try this:

```
ArrayList<String> longsToStrings() throws IOException {
    LinkedList<Long> longNumbers = populateArrayWithLongs();
    ArrayList<String> strings = null;
    for (Long l : longNumbers) {
        strings.add(l.toString());
    }
    return strings;
}
```

When I try to print the results to console, I get NullPointerException.
populateArrayWithLongs() function returns array with longs: [1488758722000, 1488773070000, 1488787530000, 1488801890000]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize your strings

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Thanks! That works like charm :)